# Need suggestion for using Redis with right implementation for the social network platform post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, redis, mongoose-schema

I want to use Redis by which every time the user will see the post that is coming from the database, I want to process it by Redis.

I have a multiple posts on a database. On front-end, we use the method of data chunking.
For that Front-end call the API and send the time == null, so back end understands that it requires the fresh 20 data. For that pick the latest post and use the limit() to send first latest 20 data.
After getting the data when the user scrolls down then again front end calls the API and send the time == last post created date time. Back end will find data which date is less than the front end send date. By this way again send the 20 data to front-end.

Now I want this to be with Redis. I am confused about whether I will store the complete 20 sets of data or store one post data at a time.

Problem is if store the data on blocks like an array of the object where 20 data will store on an array then if I want to modify the data then how will I do it because Redis will not update the single entity on a block. It will update the whole block

If I go to single entry, then how will I share the 20 data to front-end because by this way redis will store the single entity where each key is bind with single post.

Please tell me that how social network like facebook, Instagram or twitter handle this.

Also, suggest me that is it beneficial for using redis on the post. Any help or suggestion is really appreciated for that

Comment: Did you consider using SortedSet?

Comment: @GuyKorland could you throw some light on term SortedSet in terms of my queries?

Comment: I am already sorting through mongodb queries